# unable to get SSH keys working between sourcetree and github

Tags: github, putty, ssh-keys, atlassian-sourcetree

I was able to create a key and connect to github following these instructions via the command prompt successfully:

https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

However, when I try to connect via Sourcetree and putty I cannot. I've tried:

1. generating a new key with the putty key generator (SSH-2 RSA)
2. entering a passphrase
3. saving the private key
4. saving the public key and adding a .pub extension
5. copying/pasting the key from the putty key generator window into github
6. attemping to refresh branches on a pull from my private github repository from my local repo using the SSH clone URL I got from github

I also tried opening the key generated from the github command line instructions and it wanted me to convert it to a putty-type key which I did and saved off, tried with that one. Also no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

In order to get it worked I ended up going to Tools -> Options -> SSH Client and changing it to OpenSSH. I generated and uploaded several different types of keys trying to get it work as well but I think this is what finally did it.

Comment: This option is missing in the Mac client. Any clue where can I add custom ssh keys in the mac sourcetree?

Comment: This seems to work when the "PuTTy/Plink" option (selected by default by SourceTree) does not. Note that the "SSH Client" options are in the "General" tab.

Comment: Where is Tools?  I don't see this on my Mac in SourceTree.

Comment: Trying different things from last 2 hours and not able to resolve the issue.But this simple step work like a charm.Thanks

Comment: This worked in Windows setup. I had already setup my .ssh/id_rsa keys and also ssh-agent.

Comment: For mac users you have to add your SSH private key to your keychain. You can do that by using `ssh-add -K /path/to/your/private/ssh/key`.

Comment: @kaharoth that didn't work for me... it is still asking for a password

Comment: Same. Adding the key to ssh agent and/or into the keychain is not working.

Answer (score 38):

In my case, I needed to switch to a `git` or `ssh` based repo path rather than the `https` based repo path. This causes SourceTree to switch to SSH based authentication.

This setting can be found at `Repository => Repository setting => Paths`

Example:

**Correct** repo paths

```
git@github.com:<username>/<reponame>.git
```

or

```
ssh://git@github.com/<username>/<reponame>.git
```

(Note: if you are working with a repo that isn't yours, replace `username` with `organization name`)

**Wrong** repo path

```
https://github.com/<username>/<reponame>.git
```

HTTPS repo paths result in SourceTree trying to be extra smart and failing spectacularly. You get prompted for a username/password GUI dialog which will never work if you have 2 factor authentication enabled.

Comment: This should really be the selected answer. One thing to note is that if this isn't your repo the <username> is the organization name.

Comment: could it be that The setting `Repository => Repository setting => Paths` is only allowed to be set by the organization? I can't find the setting. Or is it a setting within sourcetree? Unfortunately I have two-factor authentication and a ssh key setup, but I can't access my organizations repos so far...

Comment: New Information: When I click on the `clone or download` button on the repos github page, i have the option to `use SSH` and I copy the provided path. But when I add it to sourcetree I still get the message: `Permission denied (publickey)....` but this can't be. I am creator and collaborator of that repo. How can I not have the permission?

Comment: Changing the repo path from https:// to ssh:// was the solution for me. Something so simple, yet confounded me for hours.

Answer (score 14):

To login to `Github` account using `SourceTree` you may use access tokens. To create an access token follow these steps.

1. Go to `Settings`
2. Select `Developer settings` from left pane
3. Select `Personal access token`
4. Click on `Generate new token` button
5. Give it a name
6. Select scopes and generate token (save this token somewhere safe because you won't be able to access this token again)

[image]
[image]

Then in SourceTree app follow these steps (for Mac users, not sure about the other platforms)

1. Go to Preferences->Accounts
2. Click add button
3. Select `GitHub` from `Host` dropdown
4. Choose `Basic` from `Auth Type` dropdown and `HTTPS` from `Protocol` dropdown
5. Enter your GitHub `username` in Username field
6. Paste the `access token` generated in the previous process in the `Password` field
7. Click save and you're done
   [image]

Comment: Yes, it works for me. Thank you! 
Also recommend to remove related passwords from 'keychain' because only after deleting and goes by steps above - everything works fine.

Answer (score 9):

For Mac versions of SourceTree the Tools menu does not exist.

However, you can add the ssh key to your keychain in Mac OS. See: https://superuser.com/questions/879050/sourcetree-ssh-options-on-os-x

On Mac OSX, the native SSH client can use the built-in keychain directly. To add your private key to the keychain simply use the command:

```
ssh-add -K /path/of/private/key
```

As an example if your private key is stored at ~/.ssh and is named id_rsa, you would use the command:

```
ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

You will then be prompted for your passcode, which will be stored in your keychain. After this you should be ready for a password-less login.

Comment: For newer macOS: The -K and -A flags are deprecated. Use following as an example: `ssh-add --apple-use-keychain --apple-load-keychain ~/.ssh/id_rsa`. I hope this will also last until my next restart.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to consider switching from OpenSSH to Putty / Plink and use embedded Git instead of Git provided by host OS. Making ssh-agent work on Windows is a bit more complicated than clicking it out straight from the SourceTree and PuttyGen.

If you want to still use terminal to configure SSH and start ssh-agent please see bottom two steps.

[image: Steps]

Answer (score 2):

For Sourcetree on MacOS I had to change from OAuth to Basic authentication, use "git" as the username (*not* my GitHub username), and generate the SSH key and input it into GitHub. Only then could I clone a GitHub repo via SSH in Sourcetree.