# Using SSH Keys to get access to organizations repository in Sourcetree

Tags: git, github, ssh, atlassian-sourcetree

I am using github with my own account and I am part of a few organizations. I set up an SSH key to connect to github via sourctree.

So far so good, when I want to add a remote repository I just browse the list of my repos.

Unfortunately I cannot choose from the organizations repositories, where I even added myself as a collaborator, although I have admin rights and even created the repo by myself.

How can I get this to work that I can choose from my organizations repos as well?

(I found a link in another thread pointing to this: https://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996 but I think that's something slightly different, isn't it?)

Thanks in advance.

Cheers

Edit: I also think that this might be pointing to the right direction: 
[unable to get SSH keys working between sourcetree and github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20644173/unable-to-get-ssh-keys-working-between-sourcetree-and-github)

But unfortunately after following @DeepSpace101 's advice I still get the message that

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

But I have no idea why I am getting this message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright I got it to work.
The problem was that Sourcetree asked me for the passphrase for my SSH Key. Unfortunately that was not made clear at all. Sourcetrees Interface asked

```
Password Required
For user **** on host github.com
```

I assumed that it wanted my password of github. And after entering that I got the message above, that the permission to my publickey was denied.

Only after I tried to clone the repo with my console I was asked for

```
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/****/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

Which made it clear for me what the problem was.
Well, after a nice struggle I got what I wanted.