# Connecting GitHub Account and SourceTree with SSH

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree

I am on a Windows 10 laptop with git version 2.20.1.windows.1 and Sourcetree version 3.0.17. I am using the System Git (I don't have the Embedded Git downloaded, so there isn't any interference there).

I am trying to add my GitHub account to Sourcetree for easier cloning of repos (so I don't have to use HTTPS links for each one), and I am not able to see any of the repos once the account is added. I have tried using both OAuth and basic, and also tried using OpenSSH, as suggested in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20644173/unable-to-get-ssh-keys-working-between-sourcetree-and-github) (this is also the only way I could get Sourcetree to link with my Bitbucket account).

Unfortunately it is not working, but when I open Git Bash and type `ssh -T git@github.com` I receive a message acknowledging I have connected my account to git on my laptop. It also doesn't work adding the account via HTTPS (OAuth or basic).

Does anyone have a suggestion, as this is slowing my migration of some projects to GitHub?

Comment: I know this is old but did you try running 'ssh-add -l' in a terminal (powershell) to double check the ssh key was added? I recall seeing that sourcetree wasn't actually adding keys even though I had all the right boxes ticked as well and I ended up manually having to add them to the ssh-agent.

Answer (score 3):

Check your SourceTree Git settings, and make sure your are using the [System Git, not the embedded one](https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/using-embedded-git-or-system-git-in-sourcetree-785323587.html).

[image: https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/files/785323587/785323594/1/1444984682597/GitOption2.png]

Otherwise, your local Git installation (which does connect to GitHub) would be ignored.

Comment: I'll update my post to clarify this, but I don't have the embedded git downloaded, and am using the System Git. Thank you, though. That was my first thought having read the other SO posts, but it doesn't seem to be the issue here.